# Data is not changing on first click?

Tags: reactjs, rtk-query, headless-ui

I wrote an API that basically blocks the admin login status. In my react frontend I use RTK to create a call to that API. Also, I use Headless UI to make the switch that changes the user login status. So the problem is when I click that switch in UI it changes the on and off but at first it sends the same value to the server that I fetched but then changes again on my next click, and it sends the change value. I think it is a problem can anyone help me with this...If any questions or other information you want to know please make a comment.

```
    import { Switch } from "@headlessui/react";
    import { useBlockAdminMutation } from "../services/admin/adminApiSlice";
    import toast from "react-hot-toast";
   import { Switch } from "@headlessui/react";
import { useBlockAdminMutation } from "../services/admin/adminApiSlice";
import toast from "react-hot-toast";
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";

const SwitchBtn = ({ adminId, adminLoginStatus, listData, setListData }) => {
    const [blockAdmin] = useBlockAdminMutation();

    const [statusChange, setStatusChange] = useState(adminLoginStatus);

    useEffect(() => {
        setStatusChange(adminLoginStatus);
    }, []);

    const handleAdminLoginStatus = async (id) => {
        setStatusChange(!statusChange);
        try {
            const res = await blockAdmin({ disableLogin: statusChange, id });
            if (res) {
                toast.success(`User ${statusChange ? "won't be login anymore" : "can login now"}.`);
            }
        } catch (err) {
            toast.error(err?.data?.message || err?.error || err?.data?.error);
        }
    };

    return (
        <>
            <Switch
                checked={statusChange}
                onChange={() => handleAdminLoginStatus(adminId)}
                className={`${statusChange ? "bg-blue-600" : "bg-gray-500"} relative outline-none inline-flex h-6 w-11 items-center rounded-full`}>
                <span className={`${statusChange ? "translate-x-6" : "translate-x-1"} inline-block h-4 w-4 transform rounded-full bg-white transition`} />
            </Switch>
        </>
    );
};

export default SwitchBtn;
```